# Directly use c++ stream buffer to e.g. decompress

Tags: c++, stream

My use case is reading a compressed file from disk, de-compressing it incrementally and using the resulting data.

Currently I am reading file contents into a temporary buffer allocated by me, point the decompression API at this buffer, and so on. The question is about understanding whether the temporary buffer really is necessary or helpful in this case.

In an experiment, I opened a stream to a text file and called get() once. In the debugger I can see that the filebuffer in the stream already contains the following characters in the text stream, as expected. (On msvc I found it under `std::ifstream::_Filebuffer::_IGfirst`)

I am looking for a portable way to access this buffer I see in the debugger, feed the decompression API with it, and then continue reading the file.

I don't understand why I should copy the filebuffer to my buffer (with e.g. read()) in this particular case where I will promptly consume the buffer contents and move on. I'm not questioning the merits of buffer I/O in general.

EDIT:
I did further experiments, and it seems that the internal stream buffer doesn't get used if the target of read() is itself sufficiently large. Apparently the case I was worried about, doesn't really come up.

Comment: If doing compression or decompression, either a buffer of some sort or bookkeeping (to keep track of compressed data, uncompressed data, and state of the compressor/decompressor) is needed. There are advantages and disadvantages either way.   Yes, standard streams have a buffer - but a buffer size of zero corresponds to no buffer. Rather than arbitrarily trying to eliminate a buffer, try implementing two versions - with buffer and without - and benchmark performance in representative use cases.  You'll learn about the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches that way.

Comment: Disabling buffering for the stream is likely to be counter productive. Consider bypassing the stream (and thus its buffering), and just using a low-level [`read`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html). Of course, as @Peter mentions, you'll want to benchmark all options to validate that it actually improves performance.

Comment: @Peter, trying to implement the version without the additional buffer indirection is what I'm trying to do. Is there a way of saying to stream "show my your current buffer, than fill it with new content." The copy seems completely redundant in this case.